# In R how to make two columns an ID and get a frequency histogram for each ID

Tags: r, statistics, histogram, frequency

Example Dataset:

```
A    2     1.5
A    2     1.5
B    3     2.0
B    3     2.5
B    3     2.6
C    4     3.2
C    4     3.5
```

So here I would like to create 3 frequency histograms based on the first two columns so A2, B3, and C4? I am new to R any help would be greatly appreciated should I flatten out the data so its like this:

```
 A     2     1.5   1.5
 B     3     2.0   2.5  2.6 etc...
```

Thank you

Comment: Like this.... `invisible(with(dat, tapply(V3, list(V1, V2), hist)))`?

Comment: NO like a frequency histogram for each v1 v2 based on the V3 so at the end I have a frequency histogram where x axis is the bins so lets say for A2 there would be bins from 0 to 1.5 and y axis would have frequency so there should be a bar at 2 since there are two at 1.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative solution, that is based on by-function, which is just a wrapper for the tapply that Jilber suggested. You might find the 'ex'-variable useful:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(First = LETTERS[1:3], Second = 1:2, Num = rnorm(60))

# Extract third column per each unique combination of columns 'First' and 'Second'
ex <- by(dat, INDICES = 
    # Create names like A.1, A.2, ...
    apply(dat[,c("First","Second")], MARGIN=1, FUN=function(z) paste(z, collapse=".")), 
    # Extract third column per each unique combination
    FUN=function(x) x[,3]) 

# Draw histograms
par(mfrow=c(3,2))
for(i in 1:length(ex)){
    hist(ex[[i]], main=names(ex)[i], xlim=extendrange(unlist(ex)))
}
```

[image: Example histograms]

Comment: Is there a specific way to read in the original dataset to call the columns by a variable, again I am sorry very new to R. Thanks a lot

Comment: @user2344516 you can call them by number. Or, you can use `grepl` or a similar function.

Comment: ok so i got it to work but only thing is i can't get all of them it is glitchy.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dataset is called x and the columns are a,b,c respectively I think this command should do the trick

```
library(lattice)
histogram(~c|a+b,x)
```

Notice that this requires you to have the package lattice installed